# Java create link to page in PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

My program links a position in a PDF-file to another page in the same file. So you can click on a defined position in the file an you'll be linked to another page.

I use a `PDRectangle` to define the position. Unfortunately the rectangle is visible in the document. I want to create the link without a visible border.

My code:

```
    PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();
    action.setDestination(destination);

    PDAnnotationLink annotationLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
    annotationLink.setAction(action);

    PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
    position.setLowerLeftX(bookmarkLinkPositionEntry.getLowerLeftX());
    position.setLowerLeftY(bookmarkLinkPositionEntry.getLowerLeftY());
    position.setUpperRightX(bookmarkLinkPositionEntry.getUpperRightX());
    position.setUpperRightY(bookmarkLinkPositionEntry.getUpperRightY());

    annotationLink.setRectangle(position);

    destinationPDF.getPage(0).getAnnotations().add(annotationLink);
```

I tried to use `annotationLink.setHidden(true);` and `annotationLink.setNoView(true);`. The documentation just says "Set the hidden flag." and "Set the noView flag." and I don't know what actually happened there.

How can I change the visibility of my rectangle or remove the border completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the border style:

```
PDBorderStyleDictionary borderULine = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
borderULine.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);
borderULine.setWidth(0);
annotationLink.setBorderStyle(borderULine);
```

More on this topic in the [AddAnnotations.java example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddAnnotations.java?view=markup) in the source code download.