# Can PDF notes/annotations include links to other pages in the PDF?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, annotations, pdfbox

I want to add an annotation to a PDF page (i.e. something that would show as a pop-up note or appear in the list of notes for the current page).

And in that note, I want to say "[See page 93](https://google.com)", where clicking on that takes the user to page 93.

Is that possible?  It seems like a useful feature, but I haven't been able to find any examples.

And if so, can it be done with Apache PDF Box?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (it is possible) and yes (it can be done with PdfBox). That question has been asked before and answered several times. Read the follwing answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986135/how-to-use-pdfbox-to-create-a-link-i-can-click-to-go-to-another-page-in-the-same) and the see the full code [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/annotate/AddLink.java).

```
try (   InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("some.pdf")) {
            PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(resource);

            PDPage page = document.getPage(1);

            PDAnnotationLink link         = new PDAnnotationLink();
            PDPageDestination destination = new PDPageFitWidthDestination();
            PDActionGoTo action           = new PDActionGoTo();

            //destination.setPageNumber(2);
            destination.setPage(document.getPage(2));
            action.setDestination(destination);
            link.setAction(action);
            link.setPage(page);

            link.setRectangle(page.getMediaBox());
            page.getAnnotations().add(link);

            document.save(new File("RESULT_FOLDER", "output-with-link.pdf"));
        }
```

Other answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152116/java-create-link-to-page-in-pdf-with-pdfbox) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886572/pdfbox-how-to-click-a-link-in-a-pdf-file-to-move-to-another-page-and-underline).